# How do I catch a NameError when defining a function?

Tags: python, exception

I'm very early in the learning process and I have a simple question. I have the following simple test code:

```
def high_low(num1, num2):
  try:
    if num1 < num2:
      print("The first number is low.")
    elif num1 > num2:
      print("The first number is high.")
    elif num1 == num2:
      print("The numbers are equal.")
  except NameError:
    print("You must enter two numbers.")

high_low(a, 7)
```

this returns, "NameError: name 'a' is not defined"

How do I cause a NameError when calling the function to respond to the try/except within the function?

Comment: Why would that function throw a NameError?

Comment: _How do I cause a NameError when calling the function to respond to the try/except within the function?_ You already have a NameError, you probably don't want another one. It doesn't make much sense to catch this kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown outside of your function. When you call:

```
high_low(a, 7)
```

Python has to **first** find the value of `a` to pass to `high_low`. But `a` is not defined. So you could do:

```
try:
    high_low(a, 7)
except NameError as e:
    # Do something here
```

Having said all of that - this probably isn't a good way to use exceptions. Your **code** has a bug - the variable `a` isn't defined so you can't pass its value to `high_low`. There probably isn't any way to recover from this and thus no reason to try to catch the exception.